# Get highest offer price with correct offer id in group by and join query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am joining product table with offer table using product id, my requirement is get highest offer(%) of that product, at the same time I want to make group by clause for product id because I don't want to repeat product but it is showing wrong offer id because joining query is first performed based on product id :

product table:

```
id   name
1     abc
2     xyz
```

offer table

```
id   to_date        product_id   offer
1   2020-12-18       1            30%
2   2020-12-18       1            40%
3   2020-12-18       2            30%
4   2020-12-18       2            40%
```

Query :

```
SELECT product_id,product.name,o.id as offer_id,o.to_date, max(o.offer)offer_price
FROM products 
  LEFT JOIN offers o ON o.product_id=product.id
GROUP BY product.id
```

Output with issue( wrong offer id):

```
offer_id product_id  to_date       offer_price 
 1           1        2020-12-18      40%
 3           2        2020-12-18      40%
```

Expected output(correct offer id)

```
offer_id product_id  to_date       offer_price 
 2           1        2020-12-18      40%
 4           2        2020-12-18      40%
```

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid, and will raise an error in newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: mysq l version 5.6.49

Comment: @ jarlh can u please show me query  which will never put error in future version using group by and also achieve perfect offer id

Comment: Do a GROUP BY in a subquery to get each product with its max offer price. JOIN.

Comment: I don't have idea about subquery, can u please show me once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select o.*, p.name as product_name
from product p
left join (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by product_id order by offer desc) rn
    from offer o
) o on o.product_id = p.id and o.rn = 1
```

`row_number()` ranks records having the same `product_id` by descending `offer` - so the row with the greatest offer for each product gets rank `1`. You can then use that information for filtering.

This requiers MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions, one alternative uses a correlated subquery to filter on the greatest offer per product:

```
select o.*, p.name as product_name
from product p
left join offer o 
    on  o.product_id = p.id
    and o.offer = (select max(o1.offer) from offer o1 where o1.product_id = p.id)
```

Comment: i didn't understand your query  , what is row_number

Comment: @user_1234: I edited my answer with more information. I also added a solution for the version of MySQL that you are running.

Comment: can I use left join instead of inner join, because few products don't have  any offer

Comment: @user_1234: I updated my answer for this.

Comment: sure,I  am checking

Comment: thank you so much,I got it as per my expectation, and understood how to use subquery in different scenario,thank u so much

Comment: please update your answer ,second answer is working and as per expectation,so everyone will get clarity,second answer is working